# How impulse is fundamentally different than momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Are impulse and momentum really different quantities?
Is there a conservation law of Impulse too just like momentum conservation.

And lastly, will impulse be conserved for the cases where body (say a rod)is hinged. I know that momentum conservation can't be applied to cases where body is hinged.

Comment: Impulse is change of momentum i.e the difference between two momenta. I'm not sure it makes sense to ask about the conservation of a change.

Comment: @JohnRennie You could ask if a difference in one reference frame is the same as the difference in another reference frame. For instance, potential energy difference is invariant under translations

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is the base quantity. Impulse is the *change* in momentum from an initial value $\mathbf{p}_i$ to a final value $\mathbf{p}_f$:

$$\mathbf{I} = \Delta \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{p}_f - \mathbf{p}_i$$

However, and hence, they both have the same dimensions and units (force times time, e.g. newton-seconds and prefixed derivatives in SI).

Comment: What about the "hinge" issue of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, impulse is the same, impulse is defined as:
$$ \int{Fdt}$$
and both, $F$ and $dt$ are conserved across inertial systems. If you transform into an accelerated system you need to add the pseudo forces.

Comment: Please inform on "hinge" mentioned in the question as well.